# How to show $1 + t^p \geq (1+t)^p$ for $p < 1$ and $t>0$?

Tags: functions, inequality

How can we show $$1 + t^p \geq (1+t)^p$$ 
where $p < 1$ and $t>0$?

This inequality is useful to show $\sqrt{a+b} \leq \sqrt{a}+ \sqrt{b}$ for $a,b\geq 0$.

My try:

One can define $f(t)=1+t^p-(1+t)^p$ so $f'(t)=pt^{p-1}-p(1+t)^{p-1}$.
Therefore,
$$f'(t)=p(t^{p-1}-(1+t)^{p-1})=p(\frac{1}{t^{1-p}}-\frac{1}{(1+t)^{1-p}})$$

$$
t < 1 +t \rightarrow \frac{1}{t} > \frac{1}{1 +t}
$$

Now I am wondering what is the general rule for raising both sides of an equality to a positive number?

Is it true $|a|<|b| \rightarrow |a|^p<|b|^p \,\,\, \forall p>0$?

Can you help me to figure out the rule when both sides are not positive?

Comment: For your original inequality, you can take the square of both sides. For your question, I suggest that you use the slope inequalities and recall that $x \longmapsto x^p$ is concave.

Comment: @Mindlack: When $p=2$ it is not concave, it is convex?

Comment: You specified that $p < 1$!

Comment: @Mindlack: It is concave but it is still increasing? What is the point of concavity? Now, is it true $|a|<|b| \rightarrow |a|^p<|b|^p \,\,\, \forall p>0$? because if we take the the derivative of $f(x)=x^p$ is $f'(x)=px^{p-1}$ which has all positive element and is increasing.

Comment: Yes, the function is concave increasing. Note that its derivative decreases because $p <1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $t=0$, equality holds. Now for $t>0$, look at the derivatives w.r.t. $t$ on both sides:

$$
(1+t^p)' = p t^{p-1} \\
((1+t)^p)' = p (1+t)^{p-1} 
$$
As $0< p<1$, we have for all $t$ that 
$$ t < 1+ t \\
 \log t < \log (1+t)\\
 (p-1) \log t > (p-1) \log (1+t) \\
  t^{p-1} > (1+t)^{p-1}  \\
p t^{p-1} >  p (1+t)^{p-1}  \\
(1+t^p)' > 
((1+t)^p)' $$

so, starting from equality at $t=0$, $1+t^p$ grows faster with $t$ than $(1+t)^p$ (for all $0<p<1$) which proves the claim.

Comment: What are you doing to get $ t^{p-1} > (1+t)^{p-1} $ from $(p-1) \log t > (p-1) \log (1+t)$?

Comment: Exponentiate both sides, e.g. $\exp((p-1) \log t ) = t^{p-1}$. Since the $\exp$-function is strictly monotonously rising everywhere, exponentiating preserves the inequality.